# Build output connector in old keyboard

Tags: usb, connector, midi

I'm trying to recover an old keyboard (of about 25 years old). It has all circuitry gone in paradise, but it had a midi output and input line. Moreover, its keyboard mechanics and the transducer work properly. I saw with an oscilloscope that the output from the transducer is something that resembles a midi signal, so I connected this output to a standard 5 din connector following the figure 1; then I connected it to the computer through the midi-to-usb converter in figure 2 (soundsation usmi100), alimenting the keyboard once with the original supply  (the one built into the keyboard) and once with the alimentation pin of the 5 din connector.

[image] [image]

The connector works great with an other piano midi output that I tried, but when I connect it to the my old keyboard, it doesn't work: I can see it from my computer and I can work with it, but it doesn't send data. Moreover, to work correctly it should be flashing (with the piano, it flashes!), however, when connected to the old keyboard, it does nothing.

Why the converter doesn't see the input?

Comment: Did you use a language translation tool to post this in English? A few words are unusual. For example, "all circuitry gone in paradise" does not make sense. Also, I wonder if by "alimentation" you mean **sustain** or **support**? Finally, not to disappoint you, but repair questions here off-topic, for [various](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/q/3003/2028) [reasons](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/3415/2028) (see the [FAQ](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)).

Comment: This is not a repair question.

Comment: REPAIR QUESTIONS ARE NOT OFFTOPIC. Also, seems that all mention of repair has been removed from the scope/faq, and even then this question has electronic knowledge and specifically targets a problem.

Comment: @Passerby  No, this is no a strictly repair question.  But yes, repair questions are off-topic (not all of them, but many of them).  If you examine the text of the Closing > Off-Topic > Repair option, you'll get to [this thread on meta](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/2478/is-asking-on-how-to-fix-a-faulty-circuit-on-topic).

Comment: @NickAlexeev maybe that should be somewhere other than the close screen if it's that important. Youknow, like the actual Help pages and FAQ.

Comment: MIDI uses a current loop. What kind of signal does that transducer output, and how *exactly* did you connect it to the connector?

Comment: I'm italian, I just used a translater to help me. I'm sorry if it does not make sense, edit it, please :)

It is not a repair question: I'm wondering how midi output works.

Comment: @CL. The signal is a 5V signal; "1" logic is represented by low voltage. I connected ground to pin 2, signal to pin 5 and supply to pin 4, following the scheme.

Comment: So you connected the output of the transducer directly to pin 5? How much current can it supply? Do you know how this was connected in the original keyboard?

Comment: No, I don't know how it was connected; in fact, I also tried to use his original supply (the one with which I've seen the signal).

Comment: @markrages Sorry if I misjudged the question. The OP stated that he was trying to "recover an old keyboard" which I took to mean repair. Perhaps I shouldn't say that repair questions are outright off-topic, but certainly they *often* are because of the scope (too broad).

Answer (score 1):

Based on the very sketchy information provided, I will speculate that the signal the "resembles a MIDI signal" is not, in fact, a MIDI signal.

Comment: So, the usb converter is capable to recognize the signal type and to flash only in the case that it is a midi? It seems to me more probable that it flash if it "sees" some signal at the other end... maybe (probably) I'm wrong.